# Auto Layout trying to change the width of my views

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I am trying to pin a scrollview I have to the side of its superview in interface builder. When I add all of the constraints I want it tries to change the width of the scrollview to be a lot smaller. It is constrained 2 points from each side of the super view yet it is trying to change the width, which will break my constraints. At run time it follows the width suggested by interface builder and is smaller. How can I get this view to follow my constraints and not have the width shrink?

[image]

Edit: Figured it out. Just had to add a horizontal center in container constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these constraints.[image]

Comment: I'm trying to keep the height constant, and the width pinned to the superview. Not really worried about the aspect ratio, is there a way to keep my height constant and width pinned to the superview?

Comment: The Align Center constraint was what I needed to add. Thank you.